# how to select all tables from database? use node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

hello guys im new in mysql and node.js, how to select all tables from database?

im try use

```
var sql = `SHOW TABLES FROM database LIKE '%${test}'`;
```

result

```
RowDataPacket {
  'Tables_in_database (%test)': 'mytable2134244'
}
```

how to work with this result for take only mytable2134244 ? or maybe im use wrong solution

Answer (score 0):

I think for select all tables SQL statement is :

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Then to run this with Node.js normally I use a framework like Express
But at [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp) do you have a little example of how it works